# Pointing domain from one cPanel account to another

Tags: wordpress, dns, cpanel, whm

I manage a hosting server using WHM.  I have two cPanel accounts on this server, one for exampletest.com (account name is exampletest) and one for example.com (account name example).  We have a Wordpress site that was working well at exampletest.com but we keep running into problems when we try to migrate it to example.com.  I believe it has to do with one WordPress plugin that doesn't migrate well.

So we had the idea to simply take the example.com domain and point it to the exampletest cPanel account, then update the domain for WordPress in the database.  However, one potential issue I can see is that we have many active email addresses on the example account.  I fear that associating the example.com domain to the exampletest account will break the email addresses.

Keeping the above in mind, I have a couple questions:

1. Will associating the example.com domain to the exampletest account break the emails?  If so, is there a workaround (moving the email addresses to the new account somehow?)
2. Is there a better way to go about doing this that I'm not thinking of?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way of transferring your wordpress site would be to copy the files, create a database user with the same login details and import the database. Wordpress shouldn't be able to tell the difference.

One way would be to assign a static IP address to exampletest and point example.com's A record to that IP.

Due to the way WHM's DNS and port binding is set up it will not let you set up the same domain on two seperate accounts.

You could treat www. as a seperate subdomain and add the subdomain www.example.com to exampletest as an addon domain and remove the www A record from example first. Redirect all web traffic from example.com to www.example.com or use another sub-domain such as www2.

Another option would be transfer the emails, you can either use the transfer tools in WHM > Transfers or use http://imapsync.lamiral.info/

Comment: I suggest you install the plugin on the other server as well before transferring the files, and also try to find the plugin install location and swap the files

Comment: Static IP is not an option at this point unfortunately. 

I'm not looking to have the same domain on two accounts.  Once we point example.com to the exampletest account, it wont be associated with any other accounts. example.com is a live site, so we can't mess with subdomains. 

Both of those solutions you mentioned about syncing emails seem to only be for syncing email from one server to another, not email from one account to another on the same server. 

Another answer could be that what I'm trying to do isn't possible...but I'd like to know one way or the other for sure.